# How can I log to console in a JavaScript UWP app?

Tags: javascript, console, win-universal-app

Console.log does execute without throwing an exception, but it does not write anything to the output window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Debug.writeln`, as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azawx9th(v=vs.94).aspx).